# Why can't I break out of my loop? (Python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
import rando

move = rando.Moves()
```

All of this junk is just writing to a file to give some context about the game

```
oof = open('README.txt', 'w') #opens the text file
oof.write("The Final Adventure\n")
oof.write("\n") #writes text to the file
oof.write("This game is about an adventurer(you) trying to fight through a 
dungeon in order to get the legendary sword of mythos.\n")
oof.write("\n")
oof.write("With this legendary sword you can finally rid your homeland of 
the evil king of Mufasa and take the mantle of kingship.\n")
oof.write("\n")
oof.write("Best of luck to you, Warrior!\n")
oof.write("\n")
oof.write("You have 3 move options with any enemy you encounter.\n")
oof.write("\n")
oof.write("1 - Attack\n")
oof.write("2 - Run Away\n")
oof.write("3 - Talk\n")
oof.write("Have fun!!")
oof.close() #closes the file

print("Please read the README.txt in this file")

player = True
```

A buddy of mine told me I had to have two while loops so not too sure why I need those but it works slightly like it's meant to.

```
while True:
    while player:
        #First Door
        print("You walk through the forest until you finally find the talked 
        about entrance door.")
        print("There is a Gatekeeper standing by the entrance and in order 
        to enter you must defeat him")
        print("")
        move = int(input("What will you do?(Please use numbers 1-2-3 for 
        moves) "))
```

The problem is here. I have a module that I made that if the attack fails, you die and player gets set to False but it still continues the while loop.

```
        if move == 1:
            rando.Moves.move1(player)
        elif move == 2:
            rando.Moves.move2(player)
        elif move == 3:
            rando.Moves.move3(player)
        else:
            print("You ran out of time and died")
            player = False

        if player == False:
           break

        #First Room
        print("The door suddenly opens and you walk through.")
        print("")
        print("After walking for a bit you discover a chest, probably full 
        of loot!")
        print("You walk up and begin to open the chest and it clamps down on 
        your hand with razor sharp teeth.")
        print("ITS A MONSTER!")
        print("After struggling, you are able to free your hand.")
        move = int(input("What will you do? "))
        if move == 1:
            rando.Moves.move1(player)
        elif move == 2:
            rando.Moves.move2(player)
        elif move == 3:
            rando.Moves.move3(player)
        else:
            print("You ran out of time and died")
            player = False

    #Play again
    play = input("Want to play again? (y/n) ")
    if play == "y":
        player = True
    elif play == "n":
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
```

Comment: You're breaking out of the `while player:` loop, but not the `while True:` loop.

Comment: There isn't really any need for `while player:`, since you use `break` to break out of the loop.

Comment: you need a `break` statement for the last `else` in the `while player:` block. Additionally, you aren't breaking out of the loop because your conditions aren't being met during your first break.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two loops, just one.

```
while True:
    if move == 1:
        rando.Moves.move1(player)
    elif move == 2:
        rando.Moves.move2(player)
    elif move == 3:
        rando.Moves.move3(player)
    else:
        print("You ran out of time and died")
        break

    ...
```

Your code was just breaking out of the inner loop, not the outer loop.

Comment: I took away the outer loop and whenever the player dies it still continues with the loop it doesn't break out of it

Comment: You need this code all the places where you print that the player died.